# How to get cursor using tab Key to move cursor to the next forward slash in the string of the?

Tags: c#, wpf

I working with WPF and I am using WPFtoolkit.extended for my datetimepicker. Trying get the cursor to move to the next set of string separated by the slash example:

string format mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
I have set to on load set keyboard.focus(datetimepicker);
When press the keyboard if it the tab button need the cursor to move from
the first string mm to the second set dd if press again the third set yyyy.

I tried using looping through the string assigning  Tabindex to the count lost from here?

```
int count = 0;
foreach (char c in source) 
  if (c == '/')
    {
      //Need to move to text or string after true.
return;
    }
```

Comment: `DatePicker` uses a `DatePickerTextBox` as editor in its default control template, which is a mandatory part of the control template named `PART_TextBox`. Since it derives from standard WPF `TextBox` it has a `CaretIndex` property and also `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` (all not bindable). 
So one way to go: Get a reference on the PART_TextBox editor, and set its CaretIndex to the "computed" position of your character search (Btw `string.IndexOf` exists ;-) )
Also, feel free to select the next section of the date value entered using the two mentioned selection properties.

Comment: I understand, yet I need the time included with the date picker. So I am using an extended DateTimePicker: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimePicker

Comment: In Xceed DateTimePicker it is basically the same, the editor is derived from plain old TextBox, so the functionality based on CaretIndex, SelectionLength etc would apply here as well

https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/DateTimePicker/Themes/Generic.xaml

Comment: Could be you don't have to do all that manually by parsing date entered and set the caret, but rather instruct the Keyboard navigation how to select the next piece of text. But I don't know that precisely.

Comment: Ok I will look into thanks